# Union ETS tables

Tags: erlang, ets

I try  union of the  two ETS   tables into a single ETS table .
The only way I know is to create a third table and insert the records of the two tables in a third table.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

[ets:insert](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#insert-2) allows a list of tuples. On the other hand, [ets:tab2list](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#tab2list-1) exports an ets table as a list of tuples. This means you can easily import one ets table into another one.

Not exactly a union, but you end up with a single table containing both previous ones, without creating a third ets table, which seems to be what you try to achieve.

A little example:

```
ets:new(list_a,[named_table]).
ets:new(list_b,[named_table]).

ets:insert(list_a,{one,1}).
ets:insert(list_b,{two,2}).
ets:insert(list_b,{three,3}).

ets:insert(list_a,ets:tab2list(list_b)).

ets:tab2list(list_a).
% list_a = [{three,3},{two,2},{one,1}]
```

What happens in case of identical keys depends on the type of ETS table you're working with ([erlang doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#insert-2)):

> If the table is a set and the key of the inserted objects matches the
>   key of any object in the table, the old object will be replaced. If
>   the table is an ordered_set and the key of the inserted object
>   compares equal to the key of any object in the table, the old object
>   is also replaced. If the list contains more than one object with
>   matching keys and the table is a set, one will be inserted, which one
>   is not defined. The same thing holds for ordered_set, but will also
>   happen if the keys compare equal.

Besides, you might want to use [ets:insert_new](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#insert_new-2), which does not overwrite.

Comment: Thanks, but no different way (in terms of concept insert entry to table) to create a third table.
  I work with tables containing a few hundred megabytes.
So this way is not for me. I need a way I can copy a whole table area

Comment: It's also possible to iterate on the first ETS table, writing each record in the other ETS table (you can use the first & next functions or simply a fold ).